spark - job cancelled while doing json schema inference
I have a spark job which first is supposed to infer the schema then do the real "job". To infer the schema we use
sqlContext.sparkSession.read.json(df.select($"columns").as[String])

Most of the time it works fine, but ocasionally, the job gets cancelled, which makes this fail.
I don't have access to the actual schema, but I can say this about it:

This happens in many situations with completely different schema
This happens randomly, retrying this works for the same table, it fails randomly and not very often

The logs are very sparse. It looks like this (all from the driver):
...
Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 805119
Adding task set 805119.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
Asked to cancel job 225796
(More logs related to cancellation and eventual job failure)

As far as I can see, no reason is provided for the cancellation, I also don't think it's possible that it was manually cancelled, this happens too often.
I don't think an executor failed, firstly because it doesn't look like any executor picked up the task (I would see Got assigned task as a log from an executor) but also because it doesn't look like any executor died
I also don't think it's any sort of timeout, because these logs are almost instantaneous, and the job start is less than a few seconds before these. The timing between the task creation and the cancelled job is less than 1 second.
Another point is that the actual job once the schema is inferred doesn't get cancelled, or at least not as frequently, but maybe I'm just mis-filtering it.
What could be causing this cancellation?
Which steps can I take to diagnose this?

df.select($"columns").as[String] seems to be the obvious suspect.

Hmm, I could totally imagine it getting malformed data from that statement, but I don't see how it would lead to the job being automatically cancelled.

Are there any log lines with Exception or ERROR before the Asked to cancel job line?

No, none. That's why I'm so stumped.
